# Why isn't this element floating left in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble with a checkbox that doesn't float left in Firefox. What am I doing wrong?

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3zhrD/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
p, h1, form, button {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.spacer {
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
}
/* ----------- My Form ----------- */
.myform {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    padding:14px;
}
/* ----------- stylized ----------- */
#stylized {
    border:solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    background:#ebf4fb;
}
#stylized h1 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
#stylized p {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#666666;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #b7ddf2;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#stylized label {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
    width:140px;
    float:left;
}
#stylized .small {
    color:#666666;
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:right;
    width:140px;
}
#stylized input { /*260*/
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px 2px;
    border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width:200px;
    margin:2px 10px 2px 10px;
}
#stylized .checkbox {
    margin:2px 10px 28px 10px;

}
#stylized button {
    clear:both;
    margin-left:150px;
    width:125px;
    height:31px;
    background:#666666 url(img/button.png) no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:31px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CredentialsReadonlyToggle() {
                if(document.getElementById("CredToggle").checked){
                    document.getElementById("username").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("password").disabled=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("username").disabled=false;
                    document.getElementById("password").disabled=false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="stylized" class="myform">
          <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index.html">
            <h1>Select Source</h1>
            <p>This is the basic look of my form without table</p>

            <label>URL <span class="small">URL of Remote Adress</span> </label>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />

            <label>Password? <span class="small">Source requieres password</span> </label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="CredentialsReadonlyToggle();" id="CredToggle" class="checkbox"/>

            <label>Username <span class="small">for remote source</span> </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>

            <label>Password <span class="small">for remote source</span> </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Weiter</button>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
          </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>​
```

To the suggestion of **G-Nugget** I alternated/added this in the css and put a div around the checkbox but this gives me the same results.

```
#stylized .checkbox {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#stylized div{
    margin:2px 10px 28px 10px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    }
```

Comment: it "is" floating left.  It's probably not where you expect it since it's width is the same as the other inputs (200px), so the 200px box is floating left, but the actual check box is in the center of that box.  Getting it where you want would require specific CSS and potentially a wrapper around it.

Comment: Please put your code into the post.  Otherwise, when the link goes dead the question is useless to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Replace the CSS of the label and check-box as under. Width is need to reset for checkbox as you've already given 200px width to input. Altered the jsfiddle and tested on both Firefox 15 and chrome.

```
#stylized label {
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:145px;
clear:left;
float:left; }

#stylized .checkbox {
margin:2px 10px 28px 10px;
width:15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your doctype to the html5 and I got the results I had expected.

Since the transitional doctypes put one in quirks mode, they are best avoided unless there is a tremendous reason to use one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code: `#stylized label {clear:both;}`